# Strange error with zend frame work

Tags: zend-framework, pdo, zend-db, zend-db-table

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'liveaide_dbuser1'@'lynx-u.znetindia.net' (using password: YES)' in /home/liveaide/public_html/aider20test/zyberops/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144 Stack trace: #0 /home/liveaide/public_html/aider20test/zyberops/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #1 /home/liveaide/public_html/aider20test/zyberops/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(447): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #2 /home/liveaide/public_html/aider20test/zyberops/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(235): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(Object(Zend_Db_Select), Array) #3 /home/liveaide/public_html/aider20test/zyberops/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(705): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query(Object(Zend_Db_Select), Array) #4 /home/liveaide/public_html/aider20test/zyberops/application/modules/default/models/Users.php(33): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Zend_Db_Sel in /home/liveaide/public_html/aider20test/zyberops/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 144
```

## in config.ini

[general]
db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
db.config.host  = xxxhost
db.config.username = username
db.config.password = password
db.config.dbname = dbname

acl.roles.user = null
acl.roles.admin = user

## in index.php

```
$config     = new Zend_Config_Ini('./application/config.ini','general');
$registry   = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
Zend_Registry::set('config',$config);

$db         = Zend_Db::factory($config->db->adapter, $config->db->config->toArray());
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
Zend_Registry::set('db',$db);
```

we provided all the credentials very accurately but , whenever we try to access the database [loginAction] we got the above error .  Also the action containg database operations displays the error .... In localhost it works fine....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its definitely an authentication problem:

Various google results for, SQLSTATE[28000] [1045], all point to auth errors.
You might try doing, liveaide_dbuser1'@'localhost instead of liveaide_dbuser1'@'lynx-u.znetindia.net - Maybe there's some problems .. but only if the DB server is on the web server.

Are you sure you have the authentication credentials correct?

Edit: 
Ok, instead of doing:

> $db         =
>   Zend_Db::factory($config->db->adapter,
>   $config->db->config->toArray());

Can you do:

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory('pdo', array('user'=>'MyDbUser', 'pass' => 'MyPassword', etc);
```

So we can be sure the correct values are getting passed in? (Substitute my examples for the actual correct arguments).

Comment: yes im sure it is correct. becoz we checked with normal php database connection. it works fine there....

Comment: we checked with normal php database connection- You mean non using pdo? How did you check?

Comment: Make sure the user has the proper permissions for the database.  Seems to be a step I always forget.

Comment: <?php

$host = 'xxxhost';
$db = 'testdb';
$user = 'testuser';
$passwd = 'test pass';

$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$passwd);

if($con)
{
 $sel_db = mysql_select_db($db,$con);
 
 if($sel_db)
 {
  echo "Database connection success";
  $sql = "select * from users";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
   echo $row['user_id'];
  }
  
  
 }
 else 
 {
  
  echo "cant select databse";
 }
 
}
else 
 echo "cannot connect databse";



like above code it works and we got answer

Answer (score 0):

You should test with PDO if you are using the `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql` adapter.  Testing with the plain ext/mysql API is not comparing apples to apples.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=lynx-u.znetindia.net;dbname=test", 
    "liveaide_dbuser1", "XXXX");
echo "Test successful"; // no exception thrown
?>
```

(of course fill in your password in place of XXXX)

Run this test PHP script on the same host you run your Zend Framework application.  This is important, because the same username may work when connecting from one host and not from another host.  The username may even be authorized to connect via a loopback method  (i.e. "localhost") but not from the same host if you invoke IP by specifying the hostname.

If that paragraph made no sense to you, read about [The MySQL Access Privilege System](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privilege-system.html) until it makes sense.